# Separate drop location for failed and successful builds in tfs

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

whenever i triggered a build in TFS, a drop folder is created in drop location for both failed and succeeded build. Is there any solution to create separate drop location for succeeded and failed builds. I want to keep both folders but separated.

Comment: Not to my knowledge.  I'm pretty sure TFS has only a single drop location.

Comment: No, not built in - you either will have to add a custom activity that moves the drop to your custom location or override build drop location based on compile result. Please explain what you want to accomplish with this - you can get build state from tfs and filter out builds that failed, you can also move the content you need from build drop location to your own repository thats arranged as you require ?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the build workflow template, you could use a combination of testing whether your build worked

[image]

and then do a copy/delete

[image]

on the original output folder to the target folder.

Modifying the output directory after the build seems not be an option, since the build task is one big, monolithic piece of functionality that does the complete build, including outputting it.

[image]